# OpenCV copy bounded text area to new image

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and I am using this code to bound the text area in image. After that I am filtering contours and putting the bounded rectangle to a `vector<Rect>` to copy these to new image.

```
Mat large = img1;
Mat rgb;
// downsample and use it for processing
pyrUp(large, rgb);
Mat small;
cvtColor(rgb, small, CV_BGR2GRAY);
// morphological gradient
Mat grad;
Mat morphKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(2, 2));
morphologyEx(small, grad, MORPH_GRADIENT, morphKernel);
// binarize
Mat bw;
threshold(grad, bw, 0.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);
// connect horizontally oriented regions
Mat connected;
//morphKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(7, 1));
//morphologyEx(bw, connected, MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernel);
// find contours
connected = bw;
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(bw.size(), CV_8UC1);

Mat mask2;

Mat mask3;
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(connected, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

/*drawContours(mask2, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
Mat Crop(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC3);
Crop.setTo(Scalar(0, 255, 0));
img1.copyTo(Crop, mask2);
normalize(mask2.clone(), mask2, 0.0, 255.0, CV_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
*/

vector<Rect> rect1;
int i = 0;
//filter contours

for (int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0])
{

    Rect rect = boundingRect(contours[idx]);
    Mat maskROI(mask, rect);


    maskROI = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
    // fill the contour
    drawContours(mask, contours, idx, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED);
    // ratio of non-zero pixels in the filled region
    double r = (double)countNonZero(maskROI) / (rect.width*rect.height);

    if (r > .45 /* assume at least 45% of the area is filled if it contains text */
        &&
        (rect.height > 10 && rect.width > 10 && rect.height<150 && rect.width<150) /* constraints on region size */
        /* these two conditions alone are not very robust. better to use something
        like the number of significant peaks in a horizontal projection as a third condition */
        )
    {
        //making rectangles on bounded area
        rectangle(rgb, rect, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
        //pushing bounding rectangles in vector for new mask
        rect1.push_back(rect);      
    }
}
```

Input output I am getting after bounded text ares is:

[image]

After that I am using this code to copy the bounded area only to new mask

```
//copying  bounded rectangles area from small to new mask2
for (int i = 0; i < rect1.size(); i++){
    mask2 = rgb(rect1[i]);
}
```

but by using this I only get this last bounded text area:

[image]

How can I get or update the `mask2` rows or cols to get all the mapping of bounded text areas from `rgb`  to `mask2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `mask2` will be equal to the last `rgb(rect1[i])` called.
You can easily solve this in two ways (using `copyTo`):

1. Create a mask (black initialized, same size as input image), where you draw (white) rectangles. Then you copy the original image to a black initialized image of the same size, using the obtained mask.
2. Copy each sub-image directly to a black initialized image.

Starting from this image, where the red rectangles will be your detected rectangles:

[image]

With first approach you'll get a mask like:

[image]

and, for both approaches, the final result will be:

[image]

Code for first approach:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Your image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Your rectangles
    vector<Rect> rects{Rect(100, 100, 100, 200), Rect(300, 200, 200, 100), Rect(500, 400, 80, 130)};

    // Mask for rectangles (black initializeds)
    Mat1b mask(img.rows, img.cols, uchar(0));

    Mat3b dbgRects = img.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Draw white rectangles on mask
        rectangle(mask, rects[i], Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

        // Show rectangles
        rectangle(dbgRects, rects[i], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }

    // Black initizlied result
    Mat3b result(img.rows, img.cols, Vec3b(0,0,0));
    img.copyTo(result, mask);

    imshow("Rectangles", dbgRects);
    imshow("Result", result);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Code for second approach:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Your image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Your rectangles
    vector<Rect> rects{Rect(100, 100, 100, 200), Rect(300, 200, 200, 100), Rect(500, 400, 80, 130)};

    // Black initizlied result
    Mat3b result(img.rows, img.cols, Vec3b(0, 0, 0));

    Mat3b dbgRects = img.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); ++i)
    {
        img(rects[i]).copyTo(result(rects[i]));

        // Show rectangles
        rectangle(dbgRects, rects[i], Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }

    imshow("Rectangles", dbgRects);
    imshow("Result", result);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Miki I need your help in another problem  would you help me out .

Comment: Yep, question is well written and deserves a plus one. If you have another problem, please post a new question :D

Comment: Lol I'll post today I'll look forward for your answer miki

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886273/bitwise-or-opencv-exception/34886460#34886460 miki can you help me out with this.