# bitwise_or Opencv Exception

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

I am trying to applying skeletonization on my image but it throws exception on bitwise_or function of opencv

```
    cv::threshold(input, input, 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    cv::Mat skel(input.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
    cv::Mat temp(input.size(), CV_8UC1);
    cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_CROSS, cv::Size(3, 3));
    bool done;
    do
    {
        cv::morphologyEx(input, temp, cv::MORPH_OPEN, element);
        cv::bitwise_not(temp, temp);
        cv::bitwise_and(input, temp, temp);
        cv::bitwise_or(skel, temp, skel);
        cv::erode(input, input, element);

        double max;
        cv::minMaxLoc(input, 0, &max);
        done = (max == 0);
    } while (!done);
```

The exception bitwise_or throws is

```
C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1573: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::binary_op
```

Source of Code :http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/

Comment: Make sure your input image is single channel or grayscale image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this error if the `input` image is not a `CV_8UC1`. Please be sure that `input` is a **grayscale** image.

Comment: Miki can you give me your email if Ineed help personally Ill contact you trough mail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some scalar.
For example:

```
bitwise_or(mat1, Scalar(0,0,0,255), mat2);
```

In your code the `temp` Mat has no values in it (because you only created it with a size).
Try something like:

```
cv::Mat temp(input.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
```

This will create a matrix filled with zeros, which you can use as a scalar for the  `bitwise_or` function.

Comment: Take a look at Miki's answer. If you try to work with 3 channel images and 1 channel images it will not work at all... please confirm that input is also CV_8UC1